# Flip over colorbar of Seaborn heatmap

Tags: seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to flip over the colorbar of my Heatmap in Seaborn.
Here is how it looks at the moment.

[image]

What I would like to have is the colorbar starting from the top
with the value 0 (Green) and going to the bottom with the value 8 (red).
Please note that the Y-axis points are sorted based on the average values
from min (top) to max (bottom) and I would like to keep them this way.
Any idea if it is possible to do that?

Here is an example of the current code:

```
cmap1 = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("n",['#00FF00','#12FF00','#24FF00','#35FF00','#47FF00','#58FF00','#6AFF00','#7CFF00','#8DFF00','#9FFF00','#B0FF00','#C2FF00','#D4FF00','#E5FF00','#F7FF00','#FFF600','#FFE400','#FFD300','#FFC100','#FFAF00','#FF9E00','#FF8C00','#FF7B00','#FF6900','#FF5700','#FF4600','#FF3400','#FF2300','#FF1100','#FF0000',])

plt.figure(figsize=(22, 12))
df = pd.DataFrame( AgainReorderindSortedEDPList, index=sortedProgrammingLanguagesBasedOnAverage, columns=sortedTasksBasedOnAverage)
mask = df.isnull()
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt="g", cmap=cmap1, mask=mask)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 12) 
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 11) 
plt.ylabel('Programming Languages', size = 15)
plt.xlabel('Programming Tasks', size = 15)
plt.xticks(rotation=-45)
plt.show()
```

The *AgainReorderindSortedEDPList, sortedProgrammingLanguagesBasedOnAverage*, and *sortedTasksBasedOnAverage*
are the data I am using to plot this heatmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to call `invert_yaxis()` on the axes that contain the colorbar. How to do that depends a bit on how you are creating your heatmap, but unfortunately you have not provided your code.

Here is the most simple example:

```py
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
plt.gcf().axes[1].invert_yaxis()
```

`plt.gcf()` gets a reference to the current figure. `Figure.axes` is a list of axes in the figure. `axes[1]` is the second axes, which should correspond to the axes created by `heatmap` to plot the colorbar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input and sorry for the missing information.
I have updated the description, please let me know if you need more information on this.
I will also try what you have suggested.

Comment: Let me also inform you what you suggested made the job!!
Thank you, you saved me! :)